# WebException "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict"

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have a scheduled webjob hosted in a "**always on**" website and I've been triggering it via C# requests to the scm site (https://xpto.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/triggeredwebjobs/MYWEBJOB/run)

Most of the times it works well, but sometimes, I get the error:
**WebException The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()**

More info: The webjob was not running at the time of the new request. I'm not using any azure storage nor the SDK. The webjob gets called every 30 seconds.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me understand what is going wrong here.

Thanks!

Comment: Note: Could not find anything on the web that could solve this issue or help me, so far.

Answer (score 2):

Invoking a triggered WebJob (which is what a scheduled WebJob consist of - a scheduler job and a triggered/on-demand webjob) results in a 409 Conflict if the WebJob is currently running (in any of the instances of your Web App).

Comment: Hi @AmitApple ..I am also going through the same issue..In my case I have deployed a simple C# console application which has a single print statement using Console.Wrtieline() inside main() as webjob.....I am invoking this webjob using Azure Data Factory HTTP connector...The webjob is getting triggered as usual, however the ADF pipeline is failing with error "The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.,Source=System"....any idea on this

Comment: Check whether an instance of the webjob is already running when the 409 happens (maybe they call it twice, first one runs second one complains).